# Python Beginner (need assistance) - How do I make a While loop only accept certain user inputs?

Tags: python-3.x

Python beginner using 3.8.1. I'm trying to get this while loop accept only the answers (true) or (false), but I'm having some difficulty. Anybody wanna help out? Thanks!

```
   for i in range(0, int(v)):
            v = input("Enter question : ")
            while True:
                    try:
                            f = input("Enter answer : ")
                    except ValueError:
                            continue #here I'm trying to make the program re-ask the previous input again if the answer is not (true) or (false) as in a true/false quiz
                    else:
                            pass #here the program should simply pass to next user input when the answer is either (true) or (false).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`while True` means the while loop will run forever because `True` is a built in value that won't change. What you can do instead is check if the input is valid and then break out of the while loop.

```
for i in range(0, int(v)):
    v = input("Enter question : ")
    while True:
        f = input("Enter answer : ")
        # If the answer in lowercase is "true" or "false", then break out of the while loop
        if f.lower() in ('true', 'false'):
            break
        # Prompt the user again if the answer isn't "true" or "false"
        else:
            print("Invalid input. Pass in \"True\" or \"False\"!")
```

Comment: Thanks! Works exactly like I intended.

Comment: Do you by any chance know how to use numbers instead of words?

Comment: I'm not sure what numbers you want to use but if you're dealing with simple cases like integers, then what you can do is something like this. ```if f.isdigit() and int(f) in (0, 1):```

Comment: That will do. Thanks for the help!